# Why SELinux blocks dhcpd from executing a script from writing a log file?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, selinux

I would like to have dhcpd execute a script, which for now just tries to create a log file in `/var/log/dhcpd/`, but SELinux denies it to do so.

**Question**

Can anyone from the below see what permissions I need to give the script or perhaps `/var/log/dhcpd/`?

```
# ls -ladZ /etc/dhcp/scripts/dhcp_log.sh 
-rwxrwx---. root dhcpd unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0   /etc/dhcp/scripts/dhcp_log.sh
# ls -ladZ /var/log/dhcpd/
drwxrwxr-x. root dhcpd unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 /var/log/dhcpd/
```

/var/log/audit/audit.log:

```
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1541512634.060:8940): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=dhcpd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=AVC msg=audit(1541512634.679:8941): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=18112 comm="dhcp_log.sh" path="/var/log/dhcpd/log" dev="vda1" ino=16798830 scontext=system_u:system_r:dhcpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1541512634.679:8941): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=afd170 a1=441 a2=1b6 a3=fffffff0 items=0 ppid=18111 pid=18112 auid=4294967295 uid=177 gid=177 euid=177 suid=177 fsuid=177 egid=177 sgid=177 fsgid=177 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="dhcp_log.sh" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=system_u:system_r:dhcpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1541512634.679:8941): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F62617368002F6574632F646863702F736372697074732F646863705F6C6F672E7368006F7574707574
type=AVC msg=audit(1541512634.679:8942): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=18112 comm="dhcp_log.sh" path="/var/log/dhcpd/log" dev="vda1" ino=16798830 scontext=system_u:system_r:dhcpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1541512634.679:8942): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=afd170 a1=401 a2=1b6 a3=fffffff0 items=0 ppid=18111 pid=18112 auid=4294967295 uid=177 gid=177 euid=177 suid=177 fsuid=177 egid=177 sgid=177 fsgid=177 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="dhcp_log.sh" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=system_u:system_r:dhcpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1541512634.679:8942): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F62617368002F6574632F646863702F736372697074732F646863705F6C6F672E7368006F7574707574
```

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue a few days ago and reslobe by granting permisive privilege:

[Write permission on file is NOT granted when used by postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/939444/write-permission-on-file-is-not-granted-when-used-by-postfix)

Comment: Automatic downvote for recommending disabling SELinux.