# Write permission on file is NOT granted when used by postfix

Tags: postfix, permissions, write

I have to change my working platform from Ubuntu to Centos7.

My script is working fine on Ubuntu but not yet on Centos.

My script is supposed to update the /tmp/CheckAccessRight.log file, when the script is executed manually the   "Write permission" is granted to the file.

```
test -w /tmp/CheckAccessRight.log
```

If the script is called via postfix,  the "Write permission" is NOT granted to the file.

**# cat /etc/aliases**

```
check:  "|/home/owner/bin/CheckAccessRight.sh"
```

**$ ls -l /etc/aliases***

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  5730 Nov 10 11:53 /etc/aliases
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 12288 Nov 10 11:53 /etc/aliases.db
```

**$ ls -l /tmp/CheckAccessRight.log**

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 owner owner 7843 Nov 10 12:26 /tmp/CheckAccessRight.log
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf:default_privs = owner**

Any idea ?

$ **sestatus**

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

Comment: On CentOS: Check SELinux.

Comment: Check the audit log.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the audit log:

```
*grep CheckAccessRight.log  /var/log/audit/audit.log*
```

> type=AVC msg=audit(1541841282.927:466): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=10383 comm="vismail-dispatc" name="CheckAccessRight.log" dev="dm-0" ino=16777285 scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_local_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 tclass=file

```
*semanage permissive -a postfix_local_t*
*semodule -l | grep permissive*
```

> permissive_postfix_local_t      (null)
>
> permissivedomains       (null)

I am progressing, "Write permission" on file is **NOW** granted when used by postfix!

Seems to be Ok !